# Email anti spam PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a contact form with no sort of spam protection on my site and im receiving lots of spam, I'm going to add anti spam protection, I know i can do this with PHP, but if I stopped the form from validation if an anti spam question was wrong using jQuery, would this be sufficient? or do spam bots bypass javascript security measures?

Comment: If you're form will submit without JS, a bot will find a way to ignore it.  You do need some sort of server-side check.  Captchas have been the norm for a long time and should do a good job for a while still, but I've become a big fan of the concept behind nucaptcha http://www.nucaptcha.com/demo

Comment: Thanks @Ferhad my ownly problem is the form-process.php isnt on my server and so i cant access it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One real simple trick is to add a input field with css style of display none. Then check if that field got filled. Since it's hidden, only bots would fill it. In php you could check if that field got filled, and if so, block it.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `reCAPTCHA`. Its pretty simple to integrate it and its well documented.

Give it a try! It'll totally do its job on preventing against spam.

More here https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

**Edit:**

[Official reCaptcha Webside](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Answer (score 1):

2 things I do a lot that seem to eliminate almost all spam:

1. Add a text field with a style that is `display:none`, when the page is submitted, that field should be set, but empty. If it is not empty, it is from a bot.
2. Don't set the form's action correctly, then use JavaScript to set it correctly. (Example below)

Also, a good captcha will generally do the trick, as previously mentioned.

```
<form style="display:none;" id="myform" action="http://www.google.com">
    ...
</form>
<script>
var obj=document.getElementById('myform');
obj.action='realaction.php';
obj.style.display='block';
</script>
<noscript>You must have JavaScript enabled to contact us</noscript>
```

Comment: not setting form's action correctly is not a good practice to be honest. If for any reason JS is not working, a valid user will land nowhere. You could add a parameter to the action URL with JS and check that in addition but I would not make that a KO criteria

Comment: You need to take a full look at the answer, the form isn't even visible unless JavaScript changes the display. With a proper `noscript` warning to let the user know when JavaScript isn't enabled.

Comment: you write "don't set the form's action correctly, then use JavaScript to set it correctly". I would not recommend that. If JavaScript is not working (and this can also be due an error in some other script before) the user cannot submit the form.

Comment: Are you a trying to be a troll? The form is not visible, Javascript also is the only method to make it visible, so if JavaScript isn't working, it will never be made visible either, so it doesn't matter if the action isn't set correctly. Seriously, read all of the code

Comment: No, I am not trying to be a troll and yes I read your code. I don't know how you have the idea to set the form to hidden, and show it with JavaScript, that is not part of the question and just makes less sense as - as mentioned before, w/o JavaScript the user cannot submit the form. The point I just want to make is that it's simply a very bad design if a form or anything else relies on JavaScript to work. This should never be the case.

Comment: Then use a different solution. That doesn't mean this solution doesn't work. I use this on my website's forms, and haven't gotten a single spam message via the form in years, but yes, it requires JavaScript

Comment: Sure it works (if JavaScript works). There is just a possibility that in some cases the whole form does not work and you create a bad user experience. As mentioned before, it is just not a good design and that's why I pointed it out in the comments so others understand.